# iOS Time Profiling: Funny How Time Slips Away

Tags: ios, uikit, instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm trying to use Instruments to figure out why there's a visible lag when I display a certain View Controller.

When I run the profiler, and focus only on the interval of time during the view controller initialization and display on screen, I see this:

[image]

Clearly the 500 ms delay on the main thread is not good. But where did the time go? Why does the call tree go from 100% to 15%?

How can I get Instruments to give me more information about that missing 85%?

(To generate this result, "invert call tree" and "separate by thread" were checked in display settings.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no missing 85%. The call tree does not go from 100% to 15%. The first listing in your screenshot contains the total time of the main thread, which is 100% of the time. The listings after that tell you where the time goes. The first one takes up 15% of the time, the second one takes 3.4%, the third one takes 2.7% and so on.

If you want to find your code in the call tree, select the Hide System Libraries checkbox in the display settings. When you hide the system libraries, the first listing should have the name main. Don't worry about this listing, as it's similar to the Main Thread listing in your screenshot. The first listing after main is the slowest code path. Double-clicking your functions in the call tree shows the lines of code that take the most time, which should help you find the source of the lag in your code. Start with the listing after main and go from there.